# Solution to dynamically set page zoom (fit to page) and display synpdf file pages[page1..pageN] with specific zoom % for portrait/landscape content

Tags: synpdf

Problem : SynPdf document pages dynamic zoom adjustment basis the pdf document content

Unable to find out the apt properties or function that culd solve either of below points,

a. Allowing to set pdf document's page zoom basis the content present in pdf page(s) having either of orientation/layout - Portrait or Landscape (whenever created pdf doc is opened)

b. Auto adjust/set the pdf document page(s) to fit to page(width) basis the content(text or tables) drawn on Pdf Vcl canvas (whenever created pdf doc is opened)

Both of above points pertains to page(s) zoom/layout adjustments while reading & navigating between pages of created pdf document (preferably without having horizontal scroll bar at bottom of pdf pages)

...Any possibility to get through with this problem ?

Pdf.root.openaction:= pdf.createdestination;

Pdf.root.openaction.destinationtype:= dtfitBV;

Pdf.root.openaction.zoom:= 1..10 not giving desired result.